# Firefox rendering the wrong thing when I scroll

Tags: nvidia, firefox, video

Sometimes when I scroll in firefox, I will a block of the same content from another portion of the page rendered where it shouldn't be, almost like the browser didn't scroll properly.

I suspect that this has something to do with my video driver, and some stability issues I've been experiencing. I'm using the recommended driver, 280.13.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of an example? Add it to your question if you can.

Comment: @TomBrossman great idea. I am pretty scant on details here. It turns out that I can't take a screen shot because when I press "print screen" it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a comment above, I was able to figure out that I only had these scrolling issues when I was scrolling over a flash element in a web page.

It seems to be fixed now. I followed the instructions here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/29776/36361

And then ran:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```